# How to make a box stick to the top?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to do the following layout on my website:

---

### strip A

---

### strip B

---

### strip C

When rolling down, stripA and stripB will not be seen anymore. However, stripC will stick to the top on the browsing window and will be always visible.

In case the user rolls up again. Then the initial stripA stripB and stripC will be seen.

1) How is this functionality called?
2) How can it be achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use

```
position: fixed;
```

on your strip C

Comment: But this style should be assigned to the element only when the scrollTop value is greater than the actual position of the element.

Comment: well, in this case my hands are tight.